# React render icons according to number that is stored in json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json file where I store basic information that I want to display. In this file, there is a key (level) that stores the number of star icons that should be displayed. I wanted to do it with for loop but I get errors (e.g. expression expected). Please, suggest me what I should do. I want to achieve this:

[image]

**Here is my json file structure:**

```
[
    {
        "id":0,
        "language": "English",
        "level":5,
        "img":"../icons/uk.svg"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "language": "Spanish",
        "level":5,
        "img":"../icons/spain.svg"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "language": "Italian",
        "level":4,
        "img":"../icons/italy.svg"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "language": "French",
        "level":3,
        "img":"../icons/france.svg"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "language": "Portuguese",
        "level":2,
        "img":"../icons/portugal.svg"
    }

]
```

**Code to render the data stored in json**

```
<div id="lang_content">
            {
                dataLanguages.map((element)=>{
                    return(
                        <>
                         <div className="lang_container" key={element.id}>
                            <div className="lang_img">
                                <img className="lang_icon" src={element.img}/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lang_label">{element.language}</div>
                                <div class="rating">
                                    {
                                        // here <i className="fas fa-star"></i> should be 
                                        // displayed as many times as key level says in json file 
                                    }
                                        
                                
                                 
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        </>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: just print `<i className="fas fa-star"></i>` n number of times.

Answer (score 0):

try this , using `[...Array(number).keys()]`  which returns array of numbers from `0` to the `number`

```
 <div class="rating">
   {
   [...Array(element.level).keys()].map(=><i className="fas fa-star"></i>)
  }   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="lang_content">
            {
                dataLanguages.map((element)=>{
                    return(
                        <>
                         <div className="lang_container" key={element.id}>
                            <div className="lang_img">
                                <img className="lang_icon" src={element.img}/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lang_label">{element.language}</div>
                                <div class="rating">
                                    {
                                       Array(+element.level).fill('').map(x => 
                                                   <i className="fas fa-star"></i>)
                                    }   
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        </>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
```